# Infinite-dimensional vector spaces with linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W \subset V$ are vector spaces over $F$ and $T: V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T(W) \subset W.$ Then $T$ induces a linear transformation $T' : \dfrac{V}{W} \rightarrow \dfrac{V}{W}$ given by $T'(v+W) = T'(v) + W.$ If $V$ is not assumed to be finite-dimensional and $T$ is an isomorphism, would $T'$ be an isomorphism?

I think that it would not hold if it were infinite-dimensional, but I'm having trouble finding a counter example for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the infinite dimensional vector space whose base is $\{e_i\}$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, call it $V$. Define $W$ to be the span of $\{e_i\}$ for $i=-1,-2,-3,...$

Define $T$ to be the map $e_i\mapsto e_{i-1}$. Check that this in an isomorphism. Then note that $e_0$ is not $0$ in $V/W$, but $T'(e_0+W)=e_{-1}+W=W=0$ in $V/W$. Hence your function has a non-trivial kernel, and cannot be injective.